# convert rules from htaccess to nginx

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

hope somebody can help me, in transforming my apache htaccess rules to nginx config

1. Removing the .php from the url's, so url: "/contac"t displays the file contact.php
2. Make this paths use their respective php file, for example:

"/products" shows the file products-all.php

"/products/some-category-name" shows the file products-cat.php

"/products/some-category-name/product-name?id=89" shows the file products-detail.php

I tried searching everywhere, but couldn't fine the correct answer, appreciate any help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check following links:
[htaccess to nginx](http://winginx.com/en/htaccess)